# JMeter get the latest file / contents from SFTP folder

Tags: java, jmeter, sftp, jsch, beanshell

I am trying to use JMeter to perform an end to end test. The test involves writing to SFTP folder and reading a file generated as a result of write operation from another SFTP folder.

I am able to connect to SFTP folder using JMeter SSH SFTP plugin and able to successfully write / read SFTP folder contents.

The application under test, creates an output file based on the input file (put by JMeter). The challenge now I have is to read the contents / file which is created on the SFTP folder.

The application under test writes a file with an date-time string which JMeter may not know hence I am trying to read the latest file.

The JMeter SSH SFTP plugin provides a number of options i.e. ls, rm, rmdir, etc however, I have chosen the edit option (`${sftp username@servername 'ls -ltr /server/path | tail -n 1'}`) and tried to use the following in order to read the file however, I neither see error nor response.

I would appreciate any pointers and if you can think of a better solution. Please also let me know if you would like me to share more information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're using the wrong sampler, if you want to run a command you need (surprisingly) [SSH Command Sampler](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command)
2. This [pipe](https://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/piping.php) symbol `|` is not a parameter for `ls` command, it's a part of Unix [shell](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0010.php), in majority of cases it would be [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) so you need to amend your command to look like:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "ls -ltr /server/path | tail -n 1"
   ```

   example SSH Command Sampler configuration:

   [image]

   and example output:

   [image]

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter/)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I have tried the solution above however, it did not work. I am guessing it may be because the response contains plain text. I am using demo SFTP server (demo.wftpserver.com) and the response returned is as follows on ls :                                 -rw-r--r--   1 root root    16471 Feb 16  2007 mail-editor.png
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    61014 Mar 01  2019 greencheck.jpg
However, the SSH command fails just displaying :                                                  
 === stdin ===
=== stderr ===